# camunda 7.5 asynchronous job slow execution

Tags: camunda

[image][image]After add some asynchrone job on our workflow, the excecution of some instance become slow.I use embedded Process engine Camunda (https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/spring/embedded-process-engine/)
Any idea?

Comment: What kind of async job? What do you mean with slow? Since async means will be executed in the future that could happen. Also keep in mind that the job executor does not run per default on the embedded process engine. do you start the Job executor? Please also post your process model.

Comment: On every camunda component, we check Asynchrone Before to implement the retry function when an exception fires.
we only activate the job Excecutor : <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="true" />
How can i start it?

Comment: Ok what is the value of the Subprocess  BoundaryTimerEvent? Where do you add this property?

Comment: ${wdtControlTimerExpiration} => PT30M

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your job executions result in adding timers, there was a bug where the process engine does not realize that new jobs have been added or that there might be other jobs to execute in that case.

The issue is described in [Issue CAM-6453](https://app.camunda.com/jira/browse/CAM-6453)

> The scenario for us was that we had several thousand processes accumulated due to a network problem. The process would execute one service task and then wait for a intermediate timer catch event. Because adding a timer did not hint the job executor, it would execute a few processes and then sleep for 60 seconds before acquiring the next batch of jobs, even though there were still a few thousand jobs available for execution.

It should be fixed since 7.4.10, 7.5.4 and 7.6.